# How to display a read-only list using material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I need to display a summary page with several items and one of those is a list. I would prefer the list to look similar to a select (native, with a scrollbar) but the items in the list to not be selectable. I tried using a select with properties multiple native readOnly and rows={8} but it displays just 4 rows and the items are selectable.

```
<Select
    style={{ width: '300px' }}
    input={<OutlinedInput />}
    IconComponent={() => (
        <ArrowDropDown style={{ display: 'none' }} />
    )}
    multiple
    native
    readOnly
>
    {task.devices.map(device => (
        <option key={device.id} value={device.id}>
            {device.systemName}
        </option>
    ))}
</Select>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`readonly` HTML attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_readonly.asp) is only supported by `input` and `textarea` (not `select`). The closest equivalent for `select` is the `disabled` attribute. Similarly, there is no `rows` attribute for a [`select`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#Attributes). The correct attribute for this purpose is `size`.

Below is a working example based on your code, but using `disabled` instead of `readOnly` and specifying `size` in the `inputProps` and adding some styling to remove the disabled look from the option text.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import OutlinedInput from "@material-ui/core/OutlinedInput";
import ArrowDropDown from "@material-ui/icons/ArrowDropDown";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";

const task = {
  devices: [
    { id: 1, systemName: "Name 1" },
    { id: 2, systemName: "Name 2" },
    { id: 3, systemName: "Name 3" },
    { id: 4, systemName: "Name 4" },
    { id: 5, systemName: "Name 5" },
    { id: 6, systemName: "Name 6" },
    { id: 7, systemName: "Name 7" },
    { id: 8, systemName: "Name 8" },
    { id: 9, systemName: "Name 9" },
    { id: 10, systemName: "Name 10" },
    { id: 11, systemName: "Name 11" }
  ]
};
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  readOnlySelect: {
    width: 300,
    "&.Mui-disabled option": {
      color: "black"
    }
  }
});
function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <Select
      className={classes.readOnlySelect}
      input={<OutlinedInput />}
      IconComponent={() => <ArrowDropDown style={{ display: "none" }} />}
      multiple
      native
      disabled
      inputProps={{ size: 8 }}
    >
      {task.devices.map(device => (
        <option key={device.id} value={device.id}>
          {device.systemName}
        </option>
      ))}
    </Select>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

[image: Edit Read-only Select multiple]